# TINYMCE - Paste Plugin: How to modify styles from Word Document

Tags: ms-word, tinymce, paste

My word document has some text that has a particular font applied, ex. Arial and is bolded

When I paste into TinyMCE, I get that value in a span:

```
<p><strong><span style="font-family: 'Arial'>Hello World</span>/strong>/</p>
```

How do I detect that this line of text has both Bold and Arial applied so that I can convert it to use a custom tag called BoldArial:

```
<p><BoldArial>Hello World</BoldArial></p>
```

I would like to apply styling to BoldArial in my custom stylesheet that I have included with TinyMCE upon initializing it, ex:

```
p.BoldArial {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

How can I use the paste plugin to convert MSWord Styles to custom CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a simple paste.
You could code the html in Word and paste as text into the **Text Tab** of TinyMCE.
So in Word you would have your paragraph already coded:

```
<p><BoldArial>Hello World</BoldArial></p>
```

To add the html, you could use search/replace to get 90% of the way there.

**Instructions**

Cntrl+H to open 'Find and Replace
Use Wildcards

**Find what:**

?*^13

**Replace with:**

```
<p class = "BoldArial">^&</p>
```

For 'Find', set 'Font' to 'Bold'

You will need to cleanup the newline/return manually. See pic.
[image]